# Glassfish 3.1 says "admingui login.jsp" not found

Tags: console, glassfish, admin

I start glassfish with ~/.glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain domain1

Everything works perfect. I enter to http://localhost:8080 to its web server.

But when I enter http://localhost:4848 to web admin console
Server.log says:

> ...
>
> [#|2011-07-06T20:25:32.411+0300|INFO|oracle-glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-42;|The Admin Console application is loaded.|#]
>
> [#|2011-07-06T20:25:33.388+0300|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1|org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet|_ThreadID=22;*ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848(3);|PWC6117: **File "%2Fhome%2Fata%2F.glassfish3%2Fglassfish%2Flib%2Finstall%2Fapplications%2F***_admingui%2Flogin.jsp" not found|#]

I confirm that there's no login.jsp file at that dir.

I updated the glassfish using the updatetool.
The glassfish instance I installed was by glassfish-3.1-unix.sh intaller from [here](http://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1-final.html)
Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you try & reinstall (re-run) the installation file (glassfish-3.1-unix.sh).. i have the same setup & things are working fine.

Comment: Reinstalling solved, I hope that problem doesn't pop up again.
I'm still wondering why it happened though...

Comment: I have the same issue, but did not run any installer script before. Instead, I followed the instructions here,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600646/glassfish-3-1-says-admingui-login-jsp-not-found
So, the solution won't work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on windows seven, jdk 1.6. I have upgrade my jdk to 1.7. Now everything is fine. Hope that, it can work for you also

Comment: I've noticed that as well but why? How you think?

Answer (score 0):

@donquixote

As some another helpful tip...

I have glassfish 3.1.2.2 which runs on jdk 1.6 (Linux x64 platf); I start it with eclipse not to deal with *asenv.bat*; So a workaround for me was (**not to reinstall glassfish cause I was interested in standalone app only**)... but to use url like a: **http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf** which you should input manually to enter admin login page to avoid auto redirection to login.jsp;

p.s. maybe will be helpful for someone as well :)

Good luck