# glassfish - admin console doesn't start anymore -

Tags: linux, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

I am trying to start glassfish 3.1.2 with eclipse 3.7; Previously it was starting fine *(I enter login/psw)* but I tried to start it today, entered the login and password and that what I've got in my console :

```
Info: JMX005: JMXStartupService had Started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://x.xx.xx.xx:8686/jndi/rmi://x.xx.xx.xx:8686/jmxrmi
...
Info: User [] from host x.xx.xx.xx does not have administration access
...
Severe: PWC6117: File "/.../glassfish3/glassfish/lib/install/applications/__admingui/login.jsp" not found
```

If not to delete expired cert as said [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/ramkri/entry/sec5054_certificate_has_expired_error) I  can see this exception :

```
Severe: SEC5054: Certificate has expired:
```

I tried `http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf` but still I have 404 error :(

So my question is... how to find out why admin console doesn't start and how to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for my standalone glassfish 3.1.2 was to select jdk 1.7 instead of jdk 1.6;

*p.s. I am still not sure why cause basically it should work on 1.6; its working but I am still searching the reason;*

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question:
[Glassfish 3.1 says "admingui login.jsp" not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600646/glassfish-3-1-says-admingui-login-jsp-not-found)

Re-installing the server was the proposed solution there. 
Could be worth a try if it is an option for you.

Comment: But why it worked before? I mean a week ago it worked fine... is there a way to analyse? And what about the access issue + the cert issue may that cause the mentioned problems?

Comment: The thing is I have glassfish for linux as zip https://glassfish.java.net/download-archive.html v 3.1.2.2; I am interested to have it as standalone application; I just changed glassfish's jdk from 1.6 to 1.7 and admin console started the login page etc but why with 1.7? As I know v 3.1.2.2 requires jdk 1.6 to run :(

Comment: Unzipping the file you have will give you a standalone application. Using 1.7 should be compatible as java aims to be backwards compatible. To analyse and trace the error there are several things you can do, starting from reading the logs. However sometimes it is just faster to make it work.

Comment: "Unzipping the file you have will give you a standalone application..." That's right :) But starting admin console with 1.7 throws some exceptions... Anyways why 1.6 doesn't work? Is it some security issue or something?

Comment: In order to determine the cause of an exception you have to specifically search for this exception. This is not necessarily related to the JDK version.

Comment: No, I mean may the jdk-1.6 not working cause the 1.6 is so called deprecated one?

Comment: Deprecation means that its use is discouraged.